# vscode python unresolved imports

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have a very simple setup:

.

|.env

|hello.code-workspace

+-train

|--first/src/hello.py

|--second/src/hello2.py

And the [image: the directory structure] can be seen in this image for clarity.

my workspace is located under train folder, so ${workspaceFolder} is train.

to get a vscode familiar with 'second/src' and 'first/src' packages I define PYTHONPATH in .env file:
PYTHONPATH=${workspaceFolder}/second/src:${workspaceFolder}/first/src

in the workspace settings I define terminal.integrated.env.osx:

```
"settings": {
        "terminal.integrated.env.osx": {
            "PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceFolder}/second/src",
        },
        "python.pythonPath": "/usr/local/bin/python3"
    },

first/src/hello.py:
from hello2 import printHello
 printHello();


second/src/hello2.py:
def printHello():
    print("hello world2")

printHello()
```

What I want is to run first/src/hello.py
I can successfully run it from from vscode terminal, but somehow in hello.py  I get `unresolved import 'hello2'`

[image: the vscode screenshot]

The feeling is that .env is not being loaded at all. What do I miss?
VSCODE version is 1.46.1
OS: macOS Mojave

Comment: Not Sure but you have to load env explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Just install below library

```
pip install python-dotenv
```

Add below code before your program getting run

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv(".env", verbose=True)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.

 I was able to run the file from the terminal, so the 
"settings": {
        "terminal.integrated.env.osx": {
            "PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceFolder}/second/src",
        },
        "python.pythonPath": "/usr/local/bin/python3"
    } seems has been called.

The problem is that in vscode IDE file the import hello2 is not recognised (unresolved import)

Comment: So, the problem is, that while in the development PYTHONPATH is not got called to be resolved 

from hello2 import printHello 

and PYTHONPATH is defined in .env file.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you specified your `PYTHONPATH` just for your terminal, which means the Python extension doesn't know about it. If you set it in your `.env` file then the extension will know you want it to look in `src/`.